# can i install ubuntu from an external hard drive/ can i run fedora and ubuntu together on one system?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, usb, hard-drive

hi i am a totaly new user of ubuntu. i have recently built a new system and want to install ubuntu 13.04, i have downloaded onto an external usb hard drive from a windows system that is running XP. my question is this, if i turn on my new system that is running a blank hard drive but the external hard drive with ubuntu saved on it is plugged in will the computer recognise it and load it. i have used the normal download of the iso instead of opting to create a live usb, was this the right way to go.
my next question is i know i can use ubuntu along side windows os but can i run ubuntu along side fedora linux with ubuntu as a dual operating system instead of windows as a dual OS system?

Answer (score 0):

You need create a live usb from the Ubuntu.iso

You can install and boot as many OS as you wish limited by hard drive space, so, yes you can dual boot Ubuntu and Fedora.

I suggest you run both Ubuntu and Fedora live for a while and see which you prefer. Depending on your hardware, some people find the KDE versions faster then the gnome versions (see this weeks review on Distrowatch).